# The tags on this puzzle are correct

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

What should I call this kind of puzzle?

Comment: There's something weird with the border on the left. Is that part of the puzzle or just an error?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Note that there are

> two of each number.

If you

> read them off as flag semaphore by which box they're in (for instance, there's a 1 in the top box and a 1 in the lower left box), you get the message `KEEP GOING`.

Then, if you

> read them off with flag semaphore again, but this time by sub-box only, you get the answer: **PSEUDOKUS**.